# How to mount aufs filesystem on debian 10?

Tags: debian, mount, aufs

I want to union some folder, current I use mergerfs, I try to test aufs.

When I mount aufs, it jump a error.

```
$sudo mount -t aufs -o br=./a:./b none ./c
mount: /home/t/c: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on none, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I have install `aufs-dev aufs-dkms aufs-tools`, and I can found it in filesystems and lsmod.

```
$grep aufs /proc/filesystems
nodev   aufs

$ lsmod | grep aufs
aufs                  274432  0

$uname -a
Linux lin 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ apt list | grep aufs
aufs-dev/stable,stable,now 4.19+20190211-1 all [installed]
aufs-dkms/stable,stable,now 4.19+20190211-1 all [installed]
aufs-tools/stable,now 1:4.14+20190211-1 amd64 [installed]
```

Is there something config that I am missing?

Comment: sometimes `dmesg` gives additional information about the error (via kernel's messages)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I found there have a error in syslog `aufs au_xino_create:212:mount[76436]: xino doesn't support /tmp/.aufs.xino(xfs)`, I retest aufs on a ext4 storage, it work fine.